# Why isn't Intellisense working for Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js, intellisense, code-snippets

I'm not getting the same snippets and autocompletions that I see other people have with Intellisense for Discord.js.
For example, when I type `client.on('')`, I am supposed to see a dropdown for all of the available `on()` parameters, but I don't see any available autocompletions.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to, by default.
If there is, install the Discord.JS snippets extension.

But the main problem here is that you didn't even import/require Discord.JS and create a client, you're not supposed to even get intellisense.

Comment: What Discord.js snippet extension? What do you mean "you're not supposed to even get intellisense."?